# Websocket. What type of encoding/compression is this?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, utf-8, decode

I would like to share my experience of using websockets to fetch data. In my project, I've been working with websockets to obtain market state information.

```
import gzip
import io

import websocket


def on_message(ws, raw_message):
    with gzip.open(io.BytesIO(raw_message), 'rb') as f:
        decompressed_data = f.read()
    msg = decompressed_data.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
    print(msg)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print("Error:", error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("Closed connection")


def on_open(ws):
    ws.send("lang")
    ws.send("AA==")
    ws.send("data")
    ws.send("WINLINE")
    ws.send("getdate")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://wss.winline.ru/data_ng",
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close,)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

However, I encountered an issue in deciphering the received data. I got this data:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x035\xce\xb1\r\xc20\x14E\xd1\xfb\xfc\xbfm\x08\x10E\x08\t\xa5a\x02W)Y!\x12\x1d\x13\xc0\x12L\xc0<\xd9"\xb3\x90\x96\x01\x88\x0b\xf4\x8a\xdb\x9c\xe2\xbd@o\xc4\x83xn\xf5U(\xb2"\x9f\x89O\xd2@.\xda\x0cl/4\'v\r{8@\x0b&\x1c\x085Y\x9fu\xa1\xf7\xde\xad\xa3\xc3\'\x9b,^\xb9y\x82\xa3g\xb8\xbb\xf8\xb3E\x8b\xacZ\xaf6V\x9b\xb4\x1e\xc8\xa3\x8f\xfe\x03Iq)b\x8e\x00\x00\x00'
```

In fact, as the message begins with `\x1f\x8b`, it indicates the use of gzip encoding. Therefore, I utilized the gzip library in Python to decode it and get the result:

```
b'y\x00\x00\x01\x87\x00\x01\x00c\x00\x05\x17\x0e\x01\xf4\x01\x02,\x01\x03,\x01\x04\xc8\x00\x05d\x00\x062\x00\x07,\x01\x082\x00\t\x1e\x00\n\x14\x00\x0b\n\x00\x0c\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x03\x01\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x00\x04\x00\x07\x01\xea\x01\xea\x01\x02\x19\x04\x19\x04\x03\x10\x00\x10\x00\x04\xb1\x03\xb1\x03\x05:\x00N\x04\x06\x00\x00\x12\x04\x07\x00\x00U\x04\x01\x00\x00\x07\x01\xea\x01\xea\x01\x02\xeb\x01\xeb\x01\x03\x19\x04\x19\x04\x04\x10\x00\x10\x00\x05\xb1\x03\xb1\x03\x06\x01\x00\x01\x00\x07K\x04K\x04'
```

However, even after applying the `.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')` method, the message still doesn't appear readable. It seems to be binary data, which likely requires further processing or interpretation:

```
yc,,d2,2    

:NUKK
```

If you have experience working with such data or know how to properly interpret it, I would appreciate your assistance.

Thank you!

It is expected to be human-readable text in Cyrillic.

Comment: This looks like a custom binary format. It's not known to file magic (which is pretty good at identifying well-known formats). You would need to consult the documentation for this API, or discuss with whoever has generated it. It doesn't look encrypted, but it does look binary and does not look like any Cyrillic encoding I'm familiar with (even partially; I see no substrings that match well to a Cyrillic encoding).

Comment: There's no evidence that it's encrypted at all (if it is encrypted, it's a very poor form of encryption because it's too orderly; it's definitely not any modern encryption algorithm). I'm just saying the data you've posted here does not appear to encode any Cyrillic text. There are too few bytes in this data that are greater than 0x20, and that rules out most text encodings (including Cyrillic encodings). I strongly suspect it's a custom binary format that mostly encodes numbers and maybe some enum values, but not text.